# Display 'blank' cell when it is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `decimal(9,2)` column where I want an empty cell to be displayed when the output is `NULL`.  `COALESCE(column, '')` would display empty cell, shouldn't data type conversion be required.

However, I see a `0` when I try this:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(float,columnname),'')
```

I also tried without the `CONVERT`, like this:

```
COALESCE(columnname,'')
```

I see this error:

> error converting data type varchar to numeric

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: "displayed" in what?  SQL Server is a data storage application, not a data presentation application.

Answer (score 5):

Numeric types can **NEVER** be blank. They either have a value, or they're `NULL`. "Blank" really means "empty string", and you just can't put string values into number type data. If you want to see blanks, you have to do this:

```
COALESCE(STR(columnname),'')
```

Just remember: now this is a `varchar` column in the results, and *not* a `decimal(9,2)` any more. Anything downstream that wants to use those numbers will have to re-parse the string data into numbers again.

The *best* option is usually to allow the database server to return `NULL`, and have the presentation end of the sytem worry about what to do with those values... but I know that's not always possible.

Comment: beat me to it by 30 seconds